# update data base on ruby on rails using ajax or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a text field input and it contains value of data base attribute(ref). As you can notice from the code, when I focus on the text field, the border will appear and when click out , the border will desapper.

My problem is, when I click out on, I want that the data in text field will be stored in the data base without a submit button.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('.class1').focusin(function(){
        $(this).attr('readonly',false);
        $(this).css('border','1px black solid');
    })

    $('.class1').focusout(function(){
        $(this).attr('readonly',true);
        $(this).css('border','0px white solid');

    })
} );
</script> 

<div>Ref: <%= text_field_tag(:ref,@ref.to_s,:readonly=>true, :class => "classe1" )%>  </div>
```

How can I send the value to my application?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for your help.
the solution of this question is to use a javascript function that will call an other function in the controller

```
 function loadXMLDoc(id, val, name)
{

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert();
        }
    }

            //update_ref_field => methode in the contoller with complete the update in the data     base
            xmlhttp.open("GET","update_ref_field?ref1="+val ,true);
            xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

For updating the particular record, you just call `blur` function for that input field or textbox using jquery. Call the blur function using either class name or id of the input field.

```
$('#ref').blur(function() {
    update_ref_field();
});
```

JS function to call ajax :

```
function update_ref_field(){
    var ref_value = $('#ref').val();
    var url = '/controller_name/action_name/?ref='+ref_value;
    $.ajax({
       type: 'put',
       url: url,
       dataType: "jsonp",  
       // You can use this jsonp if your request related to cross domain
       error: function (result, status, xhr){
            alert('result='+result+'::status='+status+'::xhr= '+ xhr);
            alert('Error occurred while updating the record.');           },
       success: function(result, status, xhr){
           alert('result='+result+'::status='+status+'::xhr= '+ xhr);
           alert('Record updated successfully.');

    });
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
function update_ref_field(){
  var ref_value = $('#ref').val();
  var url = '/controller_name/action_name/?ref='+ref_value;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'script',
    error: function(data){
      alert('Error occurred while updating the record.');
    }, 
    success: function(data){
      alert('Record updated successfully.');
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help 
 but it does not work : 
this message has been displayed on the alert: 
 result=[object Object]::status=error::xhr= Not Found 
Have you an idea what sould I do.  thanks again

Comment: I have wrote my code in an aswer, please Can you find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an ajax request: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Make the "type" a "PUT" if the record exists and you're updating it, and a "POST" if it's a new record. The url to send this to is most likely the name of the controller which I don't think you provided. e.g. "/controller".

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/controller",
  data: {ref: $('.classe1').html().trim()}
});
```

If you can't get it working you'll need to provide some more information about the rails code you're working with, I took a few generic guesses.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code: 
on the view:

```
    <script> 
     function update_ref_field(){
     var ref_value = $('#ref1').val();
     var url = '/ModController/update_ref_field/?ref1='+ref_value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        //dataType: "jsonp",
        // You can use this jsonp if your request related to cross domain
        error: function (result, status, xhr){
            alert('result='+result+'::status='+status+'::xhr= '+ xhr);
            alert('Error occurred while updating the record.');           },
        success: function(result, status, xhr){
            alert('result='+result+'::status='+status+'::xhr= '+ xhr);
            alert('Record updated successfully.');
        }});
       return false;
       }


        $('#ref1').focusin(function(){
            $(this).attr('readonly',false);
            $(this).css('border','1px black solid');
        })

        $('#ref1').focusout(function(){
            $(this).attr('readonly',true);
            $(this).css('border','0px white solid');
            $javascript:update_ref_field();


    })
} );
```

on the controller: 
        def update_ref_field()
    begin
    @projj=Project.find(params[:project_id]) #projet courant
    @local_date =  Time.new().to_date
    @sem = caluculer_semaine(@local_date)
    @existe_mom_pour_cet_semaine = Mod.find(:all, :conditions => {:project_id => @projj.id , :semaine => @sem})
     #ce cas correspond a un update
      begin
        @existe_mom_pour_cet_semaine.each do |a|
          if  (params[:ref1]) != "" ||  (params[:ref1]) != nil
            a.update_attributes(:ref => params[:ref1])
          end
          if a.save
            flash[:notice] ="mise a jour de ref "
          else
            flash[:error] ="mise ajour fr ref non aboutit"
          end
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
        puts e.backtrace.inspect
    end
    redirect_to :action=>'reunion'
    end
  end

when I use a tag_form, I work correctly but I want that the change on the data base will be in background 
thanks

Comment: Thanks for evry one, I found a solution :)